# Provider hosted app: App part working on it infinite loop

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I am trying to create my first application SharePoint provider hosted that is deployed in Microsoft Azure web site.
I have successfully created a new application MVC that I can deploy to my developper site without any issue. I am also able to access to it.

I have also created a client web part to be able to access to my application into a standard page using it like a web part. But I have an issue: my web part get infinite loop telling: "Working on it".

So far I have tried to debug and here are some information that I have found:

- When I open a page containing my app part, the code of my remote application is called for sure, I am able to debug it.
- Please find here information provided by Chrome. As we can see I am receiving a respond HTTP 200 but the respond content is empty.

[image]

This is strange that my application is working well except when I am using it as a client web part. Does anyone have any idea ?

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have find the cause the issue. This is because in the form of my view, I have the method @Html.AntiForgeryToken() that was used to generate the security token.
And it seems that the app model does not support this method.